# Netlogo : Set Size and Position of drawing

Tags: image, import, png, jpeg, netlogo

I have created a Netlogo program in which I imported cars using following code:

```
import-drawing "F:\\BMW.png"
```

It imports the image as background and stretches the image in whole screen. I want to resize it, but cannot do it using `set size 2` as its used for resizing of built in shapes (as far as I know). Can someone please guide me how can I resize my PNG image and also set it to a specific coordinates (say 0,14).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It won't change anything for how your model works, so you can just use:

```
set-patch-size XXX
```

If you dont want to guess at what patch size you want, you can just drag the size smaller until it's about the size you want, then click on info for GUI and it will have a patch size there.

I'm not sure what you mean by resize your png however.

Comment: Andrew Yoak thanks for your kind help. Actually "set-patch-size XXX" changes complete size of the patch. I just want to change the image size that's been imported in my screen.

Comment: Ah that is easier then. Just crop the image your trying to import to the height:width ratio you'd like. It will automatically resize the world viewing window to fit the picture.

If you want lots of patches, edit the world to be made up of more patches and it will make the rasterized image be composed of fewer patches. If you want to have a lot of the image be maintained, increase the world's dimensions but be careful, having lots of patches can slow down the model run time.